# Pandas Dataframe: check specific rows that is satisfied condition

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code.

```
def check_file():
    if os.path.isfile('client.csv'): #파일 위치 
        data = pd.read_csv('client.csv')
        print(data)
        return data

    else :
        data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':'Hello' , 'ID':'administer', 'PW': '1234'},index=[0])
        data.to_csv('client.csv')
        print(data)
        return data

    
data = check_file()
sample = ((data['ID'] == 'administer') & data['PW'] == '1234'))
print(data)
print(sample)
```

I want to make login code. So I think sample returns True.

Because in data index 0 satisfy sample's condition.

But it returns

```
    Name          ID    PW
0  Hello  administer  1234
0    False
```

Why sample is False?

Comment: sample = ((data['ID'].isin(['administer'])) & (data['PW'].isin(['1234'])) solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is malformed:

```
(data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234')
```

Did you mean to filter?

```
data[(data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234')]
```

Comment: data[(data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234')] return    Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, Name, ID, PW]
Index: []  too

Answer (score 0):

You've simply forgotten a parenthesis.

Try replacing :

```
sample = ((data['ID'] == 'administer') & data['PW'] == '1234')
print(sample)
```

```
0    False
dtype: bool
```

with :

```
sample = ((data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234'))
print(sample)
```

```
0    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: umm then why data[(data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234')]  returns empty data base??

Comment: I assumed that the function check_file() went to the else case and used the dataframe that is there. When I run : data == data[(data['ID'] == 'administer') & (data['PW'] == '1234')], it returns True. It does not return an empty database. Instead, it returns data unchanged, as it has only one entry and it satisfies the conditions to be moved to the new dataframe.